# react formik Error: invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of a functional component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm a beginner who just started with react formik and i get error message on the console each time i try to make use of formik

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of a functional component. This could happen for one of the following reasons.
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM).
> 2. You might be breaking the rules of hooks.
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React on the same app.

I've checked my version of react and it's up to date, Here's my package-lock.json.

```
 "name": "formik-demo",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
   "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
   "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
   "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": [
     "react-app",
     "react-app/jest"
   ]
 },
 "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
   ]
 }
}
```

*Here's my code...*

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

function YoutubeForm() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      channel: "",
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input
          type={"text"}
          id="name"
          name="name "
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.name}
        />

        <label htmlFor="email">E-mail</label>
        <input
          type={"email"}
          id="email"
          name="email"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.email}
        />

        <label htmlFor="channel">Channel</label>
        <input
          type={"text"}
          id="channel"
          name="channel"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.channel}
        />

        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default YoutubeForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curios Have you imported formik from package manager? Cause the code works just fine for me when I am trying to emulate the error. did not notice any formik dependancy in your json.